# Is there any known categorification of the completion of the rational numbers to the real numbers?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, soft-question, algebraic-stacks

Classically we start with natural numbers and integers, then invert to obtain rational numbers. We can then complete the rational numbers to obtain the real numbers.

One categorical level up, natural numbers can be realised as the cardinalities of sets. Likewise we can obtain positive rational numbers as the cardinalities of groupoids. Here, the cardinality of a grouped $\mathcal{G}$ is
$$
|\mathcal{G}|:= \sum_{g\in\mathrm{Ob{\mathcal{G}}}}\frac{1}{|\mathrm{Aut}(g)|}.
$$
This kind of counting is very natural in the context of algebraic stacks, where standard integral invarients of schemes become rational.

My question is whether the completion of the rational numbers to the real numbers can be realised in a categorified way fitting into the above framework. In particular, is there some plausible algebraic geometric context in which standard integral invariants are replaced not by rational numbers but by real numbers?

Comment: Can't the groupoid cardinality already be irrational, if there are infinitely many objects? For example the category of finite sets and bijections has cardinality $e$.

Comment: I was about to ask the very same thing. Many cardinalities of groupoids are irrational, even transcendental like $e$.

Comment: @Patrick Elliott I might have an answer to the question in the title, but it has nothing to do with the body of the question...

Comment: This question is discussed pretty thoroughly here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/310004/categorifications-of-the-real-numbers